# Why are typedefs not allowed in elaborated type specifiers?

Tags: c++

I wanted to explicit instantiate a template, when I ran into the fact that I need to use a elaborated type specifier.

At [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/elaborated_type_specifier) it is state that:

> If the (class-)name refers to a typedef name, a type alias, a template type
>   parameter, or an alias template specialization, the program is
>   ill-formed,...

I would like to have a bit of an understanding why it is this way.
(with special interest in the typedef part)

**edit:**

```
using MyType = MyTemplate<Many,Parameters>;
template class MyType; // invalid code
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58745481/is-there-a-trick-to-explicitely-instantiate-deep-template-classes) I learned that this restriction only holds for `MyType` and that it is okay for `Many` and `Parameters` to be typedefs.

Comment: "when I ran into the fact that I need to use a elaborated type specifier."  can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: Are you trying to forward declare `MyType`? You are out of luck. The best you can do is forward declare the components, and put the alias where you want the forward declaration.

Comment: Note that `MyType` *is not* a template (it is probably a class)

Comment: C++ name lookup is very painful to implement correctly, this rule gives compiler writers a break.

Answer (score 0):

Standard says:

> 7.1.6.3  Elaborated type specifiers [dcl.type.elab]: 2) ... If the `identifier` resolves to a `typedef-name` or the `simple-template-id` resolves to an alias template specialization, the `elaborated-type-specifier` is ill-formed.

So the usage of typedefs in elaborated type specifiers is explicitly prohibited by the standard.

At least typedef is not required to be an alias to a class, union or enum type, but it can also be an alias for a primitive type, and there are no elaborated type specifiers for such case, and it would not have much sense.